# Spring Application: hot reload when adding RequestMapping is possible?

Tags: spring-boot, hot-reload

I have a simple SpringBoot Application.
I manage to have some kind of hot reload with springloaded as javaagent in JVM arguments.
It works when I change methods implementation for example.
But if I add a @RequestMapping to a @RestController, I must restart the application...

I don't understand if it's possible to achieve that kind of hot reload with spring, or if I have to resort to other things (es.JRebel) and how.

I need first a solution for DEVELOPMENT.